# Python 3.8 mock for coroutines

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio, python-unittest

I try to write unittest for checking if class method was asserted.

```
class Application:
    async def func1(self):
        await self.func2(self.func3())

    async def func2(self, val):
        pass

    async def func3(self):
        pass
```

And unittest for it:

```
@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_method():
    app = Application()

    with patch.object(Application, 'func2') as mock:
        await app.func1()
        mock.assert_awaited_with(app.func3())
```

But I get error:

```
AssertionError: expected await not found.
Expected: func2(<coroutine object Application.func3 at 0x7f1ecf8557c0>)
Actual: func2(<coroutine object Application.func3 at 0x7f1ecf855540>)
```

Why? I called the same method. What can I do with that?

Comment: It's expecting the same *identity*, not equality. Calling the method again gives you a different object.

Comment: I should pass the coroutine into method, how can I give different object?

Answer (score 0):

There is an [asynctest](https://pypi.org/project/asynctest/) that makes it easier to mock (patch) async function.

> ## Patching
>
> Patching is a mechanism allowing to temporarily replace a symbol
>   (class, object, function, attribute, …) by a mock, in-place. It is
>   especially useful when one need a mock, but can’t pass it as a
>   parameter of the function to be tested.
>
> For instance, if cache_users() didn’t accept the client argument, but
>   instead created a new client, it would not be possible to replace it
>   by a mock like in all the previous examples.
>
> When an object is hard to mock, it sometimes shows a limitation in the
>   design: a coupling that is too tight, the use of a global variable (or
>   a singleton), etc. However, it’s not always possible or desirable to
>   change the code to accomodate the tests. A common situation where
>   tight coupling is almost invisible is when performing logging or
>   monitoring. In this case, patching will help.
>
> A patch() can be used as a context manager. It will replace the target
>   (logging.debug()) with a mock during the lifetime of the with block.

```
async def test_with_context_manager(self):
    client = asynctest.Mock(AsyncClient())
    cache = {}

    with asynctest.patch("logging.debug") as debug_mock:
        await cache_users_async(client, cache)

    debug_mock.assert_called()
```

Notice that the path to the function is give as a string to the `asynctest.patch` and not as an object.

In addition, in `func1` `func2` in getting `func3` as a coroutine and does not wait for it to run (no await).

You could try something like this:

```
import asynctest
@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_method():
    app = Application()

    with asynctest.patch('Application.func2') as mock:
        await app.func1()
    mock.assert_awaited_with(app.func3())
```

Comment: It has been more than 3 years since the last update on asynctest library. Nobody has been responding to issues for month also